# tplWriteMode property does not work

Tags: extjs

I have View with tpl (XTemplate), data for this tpl is a store.
During program's work some store's item changes one of it's field value. And as expected - tpl changes too. But, re-draws all the template item, and visually it looks like flicker.

[Sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.view.View-cfg-tplWriteMode) say that we can change default overwrite method for template, using tplWriteMode property, but it doesn't work (see example bellow).

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=".">',
                                    '<div>',
                                        '{name}',
                                        '<br/>',
                                        '<span>Best Friend:{bestFriend}</span>',
                                    '</div>',
                                '</tpl>',
                                {
                                    newOverWriteMode: function(){
                                        console.log('hello from newOverWriteMode');
                                    }
                                });

    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Hello',
        width: 200,          
        data: [
            {
                name: 'Mike',
                bestFriend: 'Anna'
            },
            {
                name: 'Bob',
                bestFriend: 'Peter'
            }
        ],
        tpl: tpl,
        tplWriteMode: 'newOverWriteMode',

        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
}
```

});

Did I do something wrong, or I understood the mission of this method wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs, tplWriteMode is not used for the first creation of the content, which is the only thing I see in your example code.

Furthermore, I am not sure why the component should rerender automatically just because you changed the `data` property somewhere in the back. Normally, it takes an explicit call to applyData or similar function to update the content of the component. Most of the time, the component listens to most of its store's events (load, update, ...) and calls applyData or similar methods when these events fire.

When you have a look at the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11u6) I made from your code, the "Change" button will change the data and call applyData afterwards. In the fiddle, the component content is not updated, because I kept the (empty) newOverwrite method enabled - so you get the console log you hope for. After you comment away the tplWriteMode, the data is updated.

So it seems to me as if tplWriteMode is working as described in the docs.

HTH!